# Selenium WebDriver Java - Cannot fill out input field in a form

Tags: java, selenium, testing, webdriver

I'm trying to use `.sendKeys(…)` to fill out an `input` field in a form.

HTML I'm working with:

```
<tr>
   <td class="multi-line required" style="min-width:120px;">Name:</td>
   <td>
      <div style="position:relative">
         <span style="display:inline-block">
            <input type="text" id="_96a1fa0eccfaf628" size="40" maxlength="64" placeholder="" name="96a1fa0eccfaf628" value="">
         </span>
         <font class="error">*</font>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The code I'm using:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("_96a1fa0eccfaf628")).sendKeys("Test Org 002");
```

I have also tried `By.name("96a1fa0eccfaf628")`, but nope.

The error Im getting: http://pastebin.com/tZ8FSwqx

Comment: No error message the text input just remains blank?  You've double checked that there isn't another element with the same id/name on the page?  This isn't in a frame is it?  It if were in a frame you would need to switchTo the frame first.

Comment: Is this dynamically generated? If so, does the ID get set to the same value every time?

Comment: What exception are you getting? If you are not getting any exception then there is another input field with the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems problem with your locator (Id & name both has some dynamic & random values). Try with below locator

```
By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Name')]/following-sibling::td//input[@type='text']")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. First click in input element, then clear and finally sendkeys.

```
driver.findElement(By.XX("your_selector")).click();
driver.findElement(By.XX("your_selector")).clear();
```

Then write your sendKeys function.

Comment: Why find the element more than once? You should scrape it and store it in a variable... then `.click()`, `clear()`, and `sendKeys()`.

Comment: My point of view ia to tell logic of solution. As you can see, i didn't determine any "By" selector.so, however you write your script, i suggest a click and clear function steps

Answer (score 0):

Is the element ID Dynamically named "_96a1fa0eccfaf628" or is this always the name of the ID? If it's dynamically named for example the name changes each session then that may be your issue. If the element is always called "_96a1fa0eccfaf628" then I would try using the "type" command or using a click command to click the field and then do the sendKeys command with a small pause of say 400 ms in between each step and see if that works.

Comment: changing the command used to put data into an element won't make a blind bit of difference when the OP is suffering from a NoSuchElementException.  The OP either needs to identify the element correctly, or wait for the element to render.